# Rails 3 – add action in controller's from before_filter

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, metaprogramming

I am trying to add a mixin to my controller dynamically depending on the request parameters like so :

```
# Controller
class QuantitiesController < Admin::BaseController
  before_filter :extend_input_method, only: [:create, :new]
  def extend_input_method
    input_method = params[:input_method]
    if input_method
      send(:extend, "InputMethod::#{input_method.classify}".constantize)
    end
  end
end

# Mixin that gets included in the controller
module InputMethod::Single
  include InputMethod::Helpers

  def new
    puts "CALLED #new" # Debug information
    load_recent_entries
    quantity
  end

  def create
    @quantity = scoped_by_subject.new(process_attributes)

    if @quantity.save
      save_success
    else
      load_recent_entries
      save_error
    end
  end
end
```

The `new` method never gets called but my template gets rendered without raising an exception, even if `action_name` is `new` and `respond_to?("new")` is `true` after extending the instance.

I'd like to understand why this isn't working and how I can achieve something similar.

Comment: sure that it's ```extend``` and not ```include```? nevertheless, i think it's the worst idea i've seen today.

Comment: What's the purpose? What's the usecase for wanting to do it this way?

Comment: @DaveNewton It sounds simple enough and allows to add new input methods painlessly and share logic with the other controller actions (before_filters and such) while still being in the controller's scope. Which approach do you suggest? For what it's worth, my first approach was using PORO and passing in the controller, but I basically start every line by `controller.`.

Comment: @phoet I'm extending the instance, not the class. I may be mistaken but I think `extend` is what I am looking for.

Comment: i guess you are looking for something like this: https://github.com/bitlove/objectify

Comment: there a tons of discussion of how to improve re-usability and object-orientation in rails controllers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution I came up with. It works for my needs.

```
class QuantitiesController < Admin::BaseController
  before_filter :extend_input_method, only: [:create, :new]

  def new
    _new
  end

  def create
    _create
  end

  private
  def extend_input_method
    input_method = params[:input_method]
    extend(Dep.get("InputMethod::#{input_method.classify}")) if input_method
  end

end


module InputMethod::Single
  include InputMethod::Helpers

  def _new
    # Do stuff...
  end

  def _create
    # Do stuff...
  end

end
```